# Launching email client programatically in android and passing email address to client

Tags: android, email, android-intent

In my app I have a contacts page that when the user clicks on the contacts name a drop down appears with the email and phone number of the contact.

I am launching the email client in the onClick method of the text view that contains the email address, using this code:

```
contactEmailText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{contactEmailText.getText().toString()});
            startActivity(emailIntent);

        }
    });
```

My problem is that when I launch the email client, the first contacts email is always in the recipient bar, if I close the client by quitting the application then do it again the email address i want is in the recipient/to bar where I need it to be.

Is there a way of passing the email I want into the client every time, without having to quit the email application.

Comment: `the email address i want is in the right place` What is the right place?

Comment: `the first contacts email i` ????? `the email address i want ` ???? Does this have to do anything with your email client? Isn't `contactEmailText.getText().toString()` wrong sometimes? Add a Toast to display it every time.

Comment: The way you describe your problem is confusing. It looked as if the email adres was not put in the recipients bar but in a diffferent bar. But now i think you are just speaking about a wrong email address taken.

Comment: @greenapps sorry I am not explaining myself very well, basically when all apps are closed, the device has no open apps, I open my app, click the contacts email to launch the email client and that contacts email is in the recipient/to bar, where I need it to be. If I then go back in to my app without closing the email client and click on a different contacts email address, the first contacts email is still in the recipient/to bar, not the new email address, so my problem is that the email address I want only displays when the email client is completely closed down after each use

Comment: Aha.. Now it's clear. So you have to add an extra flag to close the email app first. Something with singletask or so. I'm not good in that. Sorry. Try something like:   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); And have a look at yet more flags.

Comment: @greenapps thank you this worked! do you want to put it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Which one do you use?

Comment: which email client? gmail @greenapps

Comment: Which of the two flags i mentioned!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an extra flag to close the email app first. Something with singletask or so. Try something like:

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);      
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

And have a look at yet more flags.

Comment: it was intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); that did it